# Can I make a data cell link to a sheet in Excel?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

On my xls, I have a columm that represents the index of 15 diferent sheets.

I have a columm with 1,2,3,4...15 and 1,2,3,4....15 named sheets.

I want to link them as data hyperlinks. How can I make an hyperlink from one cell to point to an specific sheet in Excel?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-link-to-another-cell-workbook-or-program-HP005199514.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

1. Right-click on the cell that I want to link.
2. Select "Hyperlink".
3. Select the document that you are working on.
4. Click on "Indicator..."
5. Select the sheet that was previous created on the xls.
6. Click OK.

And it's done, the cell will link to the sheet.